# Sharing a file using CSOM in Personal OneDrive for Business

Tags: office-365, csom, office365apis

I'm trying to share a file which is located in my OneDrive for Business using the SharePoint CSOM library including PNP external sharing library. This however, returns the following error message:

> CrossSiteRequestNotSupported
>
> MountPoint security error: host web isn't a personal site

The code I'm using to produce this error is:

```
var profileLoader = ProfileLoader.GetProfileLoader(ctx);
UserProfile profile = profileLoader.GetUserProfile();
Site personalSite = profile.PersonalSite;
ctx.Load(personalSite);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
rootWeb = personalSite.RootWeb;
ctx.Load(rootWeb);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
rootWeb.ShareDocument(id, email, ExternalSharingDocumentOption.View, true);
```

Comment: Please provide the relevant parts of your code, so we can get a better insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured out what my problem was. I had an error in my tenant URL.

At first it was:

```
 https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/
```

Which works for sharing documents within our SharePoint teamsite. For sharing documents in the Personal OneDrive for Business however, I had to adjust the URL to the following:

```
https://<tenant>-my.sharepoint.com
```